# Laptop not connecting after Upgrade memory

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, asus-laptop

I have a notebook ASUS X555YI
The manufacturer's website says:

DDR3L 1600MHz SDRAM, OnBoard Memory 2 GB / 4 GB, 1x DIMM socket DIMM Up to 8G

I bought this memory:

Corsair CMSX8GX3M1A1600C10 Vengeance High Performance Memoria per Notebook da 8 GB (1x8 GB), DDR3, 1600 MHz, CL10, SODIMM, 1.5 V, Nero

https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B0076W9Q4Q/

When connecting, does not enter the BIOS and the screen remains black.
The light of the HD does not light.

When I remove the new Memory, everything is back to normal.

What can it be?

Answer (score 2):

From your post, the laptop used [DDR3L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#DDR3L_and_DDR3U_extensions). Notice the `L` which means low power, in this case 1.35v

The product you linked to is not low power. It is the normal 1.5v, not 1.35v.

Comment: So you mean that if 8GB 1600MHz DDR3L work?

Comment: It should. But use one of the many product checkers like http://www.corsair.com/en/memory-finder (and its other brand similars). Or manually check for 1) right format, in your case SO-DIMM (small outline, aka laptop). 2) Right type: DDR3, right voltage (see the link in the post to read up on that on wikipedia).